# Broccoli and cabbage leaves are curling (seedlings)

Tags: seedlings

This is my first year for growing anything and I am having some issues with my broccoli and cabbage seedlings. For the longest time (2 weeks) they have been doing fine but recently the leaves are curling and shriving. Looking almost like they were shoved in a dehydrator. But the rest of the plant is just as good as ever. I don't know if this is lack of water since I give them water whenever the soil gets dry. So every two days? Is it something I am doing or is this natural?

[image: Broccoli seedligns]

Above is the picture and I edited the picture to point the bad ones, which are obvious anyway. These seedlings are in these cell trays in the basement. The soil mix is potting soil (50%) and coco coir (50%). I didn't get a good picture of the cabbage, I have a very cheap camera. Also wanted to mention, the leaves looked dried up but are not actually dried up.

Comment: A photo and more info please, such as, are these growing in or outdoors, in containers or in the ground?

Comment: @Bamboo I will add a picture and add that information later, no problem!

Comment: based upon description alone they need some water since they're shriveling like dehydrated leaves, not soggy leaves

Comment: @blackthumb That what I thought but they have had at minimal moist soil for a while now. And its not all of them, it is some of them. The stems are also doing just fine.

Comment: Basement? What light are you providing for them?

Comment: @GrahamChiu yes in the basement. I have blue/red grow lights for them right above. There off for the picture. Otherwise they get 14 hrs of light.

Comment: Doesn't look as though the wattage is high enough

Comment: @GrahamChiu Maybe, there pretty bright being LED, but they are only 10 watts, covering a square foot. But I have two per shelf of my little green house, were I have them sitting. But wouldn't lack of light/power cause the leaves to yellow or something else?